# Как маппать данные в БД с помощью ORM?

Tags: java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как работать с данной технологией ? 
Чтобы таблицы, поля в них сами создавались и заполнялись с помощью  ORM?
Нужно ли подключать какие-то библиотеки там и т.д.?
Везде переискал, не нашел гайда..

Comment: hibernate и ничего не нашли?

Comment: @ArchDemon Ну я уже сам Hibernate изучил, к Spring подобрался, но вот только сейчас узнал, что можно таблицы не создавать вручную и не заполнять их, а делать это на автопилоте, поэтому и спрашиваю

Comment: Видимо плохо Вы `Hibernate` изучили

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Для создание таблиц в базе данных с помощью `Spring` и `Hibernater` используются следующие параметры в `application.properties`

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

После первого запуска и создание таблиц, его лучше перевести в

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=validate # или же update
```

Comment: Ужасный ответ: 1. Создание таблиц из сущностей это фишка `Hibernate` и `Spring` не имеет к этому никакого отношения. 2. Эти параметры используются в `Spring Boot` (а это дополнительный модуль, с которым автор еще возможно не знаком). 3. [Использовать `hbm2ddl=update` в production не рекомендуется](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221379/hibernate-hbm2ddl-auto-update-in-production)

Comment: Согласен, ответ не к вопросу (вопрос задан как то не так), ответ к комментарию. И не понятно что вы минисуете, если Автору это помогло и он принял этот ответ.